# syntax error in string in query expression

Tags: vb.net

im getting error where "Syntax error in string in query EXPRESSION 'Username = user' i think the problem is in "me.Username.tag" but im stuck.

```
conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "select Username, fname,  lname, mname, [password], [level], Question, answer from Instructor where Username= '" & Me.txtusername.Tag

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                Me.txtusername.Tag = dr("Username")
                Me.txtfname.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("fname")), dr("fname"), "")
                Me.txtlname.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("lname")), dr("lname"), "")
                Me.txtinitial.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("mname")), dr("mname"), "")
                Me.txtpassword.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("password")), dr("password"), "")
                Me.lbllevel.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("level")), dr("level"), "")
                Me.txtusername.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Username")), dr("Username"), "")
                Me.cmbquestion.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("Question")), dr("Question"), "")
                Me.txtanswer.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(dr("answer")), dr("answer"), "")
            End While
        End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not closing the single quote.

Try with this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Username, fname,  lname, mname, [password], [level], Question, answer from Instructor where Username= '" & Me.txtusername.Tag & "'"
```

Comment: my bad, so simple, its been 2 days practicing code in vb.net thats why. :D 
thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close your quotes in the query:

```
where Username= '" & Me.txtusername.Tag
```

should be:

```
where Username= '" & Me.txtusername.Tag & "'"
```

***Important***: Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Please use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx).  Something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Username, fname,  lname, mname, [password], [level], Question, answer from Instructor where Username= @username"
Dim parameter As New SqlParameter()
parameter.ParameterName = "@username"
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
parameter.Value = Me.txtusername.Tag
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not closed the single quote which is opened at the end of the query